# Controller Rendering fields are NOT accessible to edit

Tags: sitecore-api

I am unable to edit cacheable fields via API and if I edit once from the content editor then I can edit via API. Trying to enable cacheable for all renderings via API at the rendering level. These fields are not in the FIELDS property unless the cacheable section is edited ONCE via the content editor.

The item is of data template    /sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Renderings/Controller rendering

I am able to enable or disable cacheable and vary by data AFTER the cacheable section fields are edited once via the content editor however the below code fails for any renderings whose cacheable properties aren't edited after it's creation.

```
    var rootRendering = Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/layout/Renderings");
    if (rootRendering != null)
    {
        var renderings = rootRendering.Axes.GetDescendants();           
        foreach (var item in renderings)
        {               
                item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                item.Fields.ReadAll();
                item.Fields["Cacheable"].Value = "1";
                item.Fields["VaryByData"].Value = "1";                    
                item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to edit the rendering item?\

Comment: Rendering Parameters are not items and don't have fields

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes, trying to enable cacheable properties at a rendering level.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I am referring to the controller rendering, I am able to get the item but not the cacheable section.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore?

Comment: Do you have any folders under Renderings item? Add a check if "item" is of a Controller Rendering type. And try using 'item["Cacheable"] = "1"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Caching properties by using the RenderingItem class? I assume you are getting all rendering items or the current rendering in the controller and you can set the caching option on them

```
            var renderings = Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Context.Device, false);    
            foreach (var rendering in renderings)
            {
                rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.Cacheable = true;
                rendering.RenderingItem.Caching.VaryByData = true;
                rendering.Settings.Caching.Cacheable = true;
                rendering.Settings.Caching.VaryByData = true;
            }
```

Not sure if this is an option but you can also use powershell to loop through all rendering items and set Cacheable on them:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\layout\Renderings" -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.Cacheable -eq "0" } | 
    ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "Enable caching on $($_.Name)"; $_.Cacheable = "1" }
```

I did a quick test on a vanilla instance and it seems that if you add the `SecurityDisabler` context it will work:

```
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                item["Cacheable"] = "1";
                item["VaryByData"] = "1";
                item.Editing.EndEdit();
            }
```

Comment: I am not doing for the current item. Please see the above updated code and doing for all renderings at /sitecore/layout/Renderings

Comment: I updated my answer with powershell script in case you consider that approach

Comment: Cristi Thank you but we want the regular c# code as there is additional custom logic that needs to be implemented determining whether to enable or disable etc and it is not feasible easily via powershell. I am just showing a sample c# snippet that is failing in the out of box vanilla install

Comment: I updated the answer with the c# code that is working on my instance